# Npm start in angular takes a long time

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I am using visual studio code to run angular projects.
While running the server through npm start, my laptop takes a lot of time compared to others. Is it related to my pc specifications or I can do something to improve it?
I think my Pc Specs are suitable for npm to run smoothly
64 bit 2TB HD i5 processor

Comment: Are you using 32-Bit or 64-Bit NodeJS? And are you on a 32- or 64-bit System?

Comment: 64 bit System @evayly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to just run the project to develop it you should be using `ng serve` (you must have the angular cli installed). `ng serve` builds the project into ram and watches your files for changes, so it is very fast.

If you are trying to run your project for other people to use, you should be using `ng build` and/or `ng build --prod` to build your project and then a web server to serve it from there on.

You can even add addtional parameters to `ng build` such as `--build-optimizer=true` or `--sourcemaps=false` to optimize the output.

You can find a more detailed guide and all the parameters [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Regarding the build time, afaik there is no way of speeding it up, but builds are usually only done every once in a while, so you should have no problems with a couple of minutes of build time.

Comment: In my case ng serve command never starts.. waited almost 20+ minutes...